# Regex to insert space after every 4 characters?

Tags: regex, vbscript

Using VBScript 5.5 Regex, how can I replace a string so that there's a space after every 4 characters?

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
Dim rex As New RegExp

rex.IgnoreCase = True
rex.Global = True
rex.Pattern = ".{4}"

Dim newString as String
newString = Trim$(rex.Replace(Trim$(inputString), "$0 "))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need group () and a better ref ($1):

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Global = True
>> r.Pattern = "(.{4})"
>> WScript.Echo r.Replace("1234567890123", "$1 ")
>>
1234 5678 9012 3
>>
```